# Webhook call failed

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have created new agent and enables the fulfillment for Default Welcome Intent and also enabled the inline editor but when I invoked my welcome intent in simulator then it gives me default response instead of fulfillment response.

Am I doing something wrong?

this is my code

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }


  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);

});
```

Comment: Anyone has answer for this..

Comment: Are there any logs in the firebase console?

Comment: yes it showing an error `Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail`

Comment: That's a warning, but you should update your question to include that and anything else that may be in the firebase console. You may also want to turn on "Log Interactions to Google Cloud" in the Dialogflow console and update the question with whatever other logs that come from there.

Comment: updated my question with the snapshot of logs

Comment: did someone got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my code and now it's working

this is my new code

```
'use strict'; 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {dialogflow} = require ('actions-on-google');
const {Suggestions} = require ('actions-on-google');
const WELCOME_INTENT = 'Default Welcome Intent';
const FALLBACK_INTENT = 'Default Fallback Intent';

const app = dialogflow();

app.intent(FALLBACK_INTENT, (conv) => {
    conv.ask("Sorry! Could you please repeat that?");
});

app.intent(WELCOME_INTENT, (conv) => {
    conv.ask("Hello!");
    conv.ask("What you would like to do?");    
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```